# Как спарсить HTML код из элемента c помощью Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как спарсить текст элемента разобрался, но как получить вложенный html из элемента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсказали:

Вывод будет включать и сам див:

```
parse.search('#some_div').to_s
```

А вот так не будет:

```
parse.search('#some_div/*').to_s
```